# CUDA: invalid device ordinal

Tags: cuda

I have the following problem. I want to allow my users to choose which GPU to run on. So I was testing on my machine which has only one GPU (device 0) what would happen if they choose a device which doesn't exist.

If I do `cudaSetDevice(0);` it will work fine.

If I do: `cudaSetDevice(1);` it will crash with `invalid device ordinal` (I can handle this as the function returns an error).

If I do: `cudaSetDevice(0); cudaSetDevice(1);` it will crash with `invalid device ordinal` (I can handle this as the function returns an error).

**However!** If I do: `cudaSetDevice(1); cudaSetDevice(0);` the second command returns success but on the first calculation I try to compute on my GPU it will crash with `invalid device ordinal`. I cannot handle this because the second command does not return an error!

It seems to me like the first cudaSetDevice leaves something lying around which affects the second command?

Thanks very much!

**Solution:** (Thanks to  Robert Crovella!).
I was handling the errors like:

```
error = cudaSetDevice(1); 
if (error) { blabla }
```

But apparently you need to call cudaGetLastError() after the cudaSetDevice(1) because otherwise the error message is not removed from some error stack and it just crashes later on where I was doing  cudaGetLastError() for another function even though there was no error at this point.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You have to check how many GPU's are available in your system first. It's possible by the use of `cudaGetDeviceCount`.

```
int deviceCount = 0;
cudaGetDeviceCount(&deviceCount);
```

Then check if the user input is greater than the available devices.

```
if (userDeviceInput < deviceCount)
{
  cudaSetDevice(userDeviceInput);
}
else
{
  printf("error: invalid device choosen\n");
}
```

Remind that`cudaSetDevice`is 0-index-based! Therefor I check `userDeviceInput < deviceCount`.

Comment: Yes, this is a nice way to avoid it. I would like to know though why it doesn't work.

Comment: It helps if you show a *complete* example.  Your error checking may be using `cudaPeekAtLastError()` which does *not* clear the error code.  It returns the last error - every time you ask for it (like after your kernel launch).  Instead, `cudaGetLastError()` will clear the error that it returned (i.e. a future check will no longer return that error, it will return `cudaSuccess` if no new errors occur).  This is different than the API return error code.  If you want the kernel launch not to fail, do `cudaGetLastError` somewhere before it, but after the illegal `cudaSetDevice(1)` call.

Comment: I should have said "If you want the kernel launch not to *appear to* fail..."

Comment: @Robert, can you post this as an answer so I can accept it? Because you were obviously correct :) Thanks a lot!

Comment: I was actually only checking the value returned from cudaSetDevice which contains the error but does not remove it from the error stack of cudaGetLastError.

Comment: I believe hubs answer plus my comment makes a good response.  You're welcome to accept it if you like.  My comment alone, without you actually showing the type of error checking you were doing in detail, probably wouldn't make much sense.  We can already see that my comment was wrong because you were not using `cudaPeekAtLastError`.  The lack of a crisp example in your question made it difficult for anyone to answer.